# Error while loading data in Postgresql exported from SQL Server and encoded in UTF-8 using Powershell

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, powershell, utf-8

I need to export data from SQL Server 2012 and load in Postgresql. The table contains data with special characters.To load data in Postgresql, I am  converting it from the default SQL Server format to UTF-8 using Powershell.

Following is the table in SQL Server 2012:

```
CREATE TABLE sch1.tab1(
    PK_NameID INT NOT NULL,
    Code char(2) NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(300) NOT NULL,
    );
```

Following is sample data from CSV file:

```
1,ab,Test1
2,cd,Test3
```

The table structure is similar in Postgresql(I had to double the sizes for char and nvarchar fields in Postgresql). I am using \copy command.

After encoding in UTF-8 using Powershell, when I am trying to load the data, I receive following error:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1"
>
> CONTEXT:  COPY geoname, line 1, column pk_nameid: "1"

Following is the Powershell command for converting into UTF-8:

```
Get-Content .\tab1.txt | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 tab1-utf8.txt
```

Did the UTF-8 encoding of integer field convert the values into some other data type? The string fields are fine after increasing the size but the rows are not getting inserted with the integer field.

Comment: My bad. I added the Powershell command.

Comment: OK; how are you doing the export from SQL server? Get-Content should read it OK if it's ASCII, UTF8+BOM, UCS2-LE (which I think might be SQL Server's default). So the two ways I can see it might be screwed up - if the export is UTF8-BOM - in which case the PowerShell would mess it up but there would be no need for the PowerShell at all - or if the export was already corrupt, e.g. by exporting as ASCII

Comment: The command used for exporting data from SQL server is:                                   bcp "SELECT * FROM sch1.dbo.tab1" queryout C:\tab1.txt -w -T -S "localhost"

Comment: Any suggestions?